# I can be an Ange but not an Andrew

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I can be a bit but not a lot.
I can be a deal but not a rip.
I can be an ally but not an enemy.
I can be an Ange but not an Andrew.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> OR

As in

> orbit
>  ordeal
>  orally
>  orange

But not

> orlot
>  orrip
>  orenemy
>  orandrew